# Swift Does not see data

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface

I am trying to parse the data and display on the screen but i am getting " Value of type 'EmployeeData' has no member 'employee_name' "
What i am missing ?
I created my struct, parsed data and tried to divide into two parts. first part will be related with listing, second part is all data.

```
struct EmployeeData: Codable {
    var data: Employee
    var status: String
}

struct Employee: Codable {

    var employee_name: String
    var employee_salary: String
    var employee_age: String
}
```

---

```
class WebServices {

    func getData(completion: @escaping (EmployeeData?) -> ()){


        guard let url = URL(string:"http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees")
        else { fatalError("There is error!") }

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response,error) in

            guard let data = data, error == nil else {

                DispatchQueue.main.async{
                completion(nil)
                }
                return
            }

            let empleyees = try? JSONDecoder().decode(EmployeeData.self, from: data)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(empleyees)
            }


        }.resume()


    }
}
```

---

```
class MVDesingnListView: ObservableObject {

}


struct MVDesignCellView {

    let employeeDatas: EmployeeData

    init(employeeDatas: EmployeeData) {
        self.employeeDatas = employeeDatas
    }

    var employee_name: String {
        self.employeeDatas.employee_name            
    }
}
```

Comment: A couple of other tips don't use `try?`. Use `do/try/catch` is that you have a chance to handle or at least print any errors that occur. Also, use `CodingKeys` to map the un-Swifty property names with _ to camel case names (ie `employeeName` instead of `employee_name`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler is all right. Your struct `EmployeeData` has no member `employee_name`.

You need to go to the employee first, to get her name:

```
var employee_name: String {
    self.employeeDatas.data.employee_name            
}
```

should do the job.

Comment: Andreas , I want to create ListView but i get " Value of type 'EmployeeData' has no member 'map' " . can u help me to fix that one too? Thank u 
------------------------------------------
class MVDesingnListView: ObservableObject {
    
  @Published var userssInfo = [MVDesignCellView]()
       
       init() {
           WebServices().getData { userssInfo in
               
               if let userssInfo = userssInfo {
                   
                   self.userssInfo = userssInfo.map(MVDesignCellView.init)
                
               }
           }
       }
    
}

Comment: On your `map` question: You need an array (or some other collection) to use map. But you should create a new question regarding this, show more of your list view class, and tag the question with the `SwiftUI` keyword